# Python Distutils Package Distribution

Tags: python

I am trying to create a package installer using `distutils` on Python 2.7.

Here's my `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import distutils.command.bdist as bdist

setup_options = {
    'name': 'tk',
    'version': '1.0',
    'description': 'Graphics package that supplements native Tkinter',
    'package_dir': {'tk': ''},
    # this is because setup.py is in the same directory as the package contents
    'packages': ['tk', 'tk.latex'],
    }

setup(**setup_options)
```

Using `python setup.py bdist --format=wininst`, then using 7-Zip to look through the executable, I find this directory of files and folders:

```
PURELIB/ # excepted for the executable
    tk/ # also expected
    latex/ # subpackage, should not be here
    some_file_in_tk.py # this should only be located in tk, not in this main directory
```

When using the installer on another computer, it installs the `tk` package under `site-packages`, as expected. However, it also installs the `latex` subpackage (which is in `tk`) and all other files in `tk`. Why does this happen, and can I resolve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Examples from the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/examples.html#pure-python-distribution-by-package) suggest the following directory layout:

```
<root>
├── setup.py
└── tk
    ├── __init__.py
    └── latex
        └── __init__.py
```

where `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='tk',
    version='1.0',
    description='Graphics package that supplements native Tkinter',
    packages=['tk', 'tk.latex'],
)
```